# How to make the hover effect on the before content, which is "\f00d", only?

Tags: html, css

I want my hover effect to activate only when I hover it to the before content.

[image]

[image]

Comment: show your code not image

Comment: can you please send your code here

Answer (score 1):

Use `fryd-viewer-wrapper:hover:before`

```css
a:before {
   font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
   content: "\f008";
   font-weight: 900;
}
a:hover:before {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<a>Try me</a>
```